Apache NiFi to Oracle: Null Password
I've trying to set a connection from NiFi to Oracle for an ETL process. Listeners are set in Oracle to accept connections from NiFi's host address. The issue happens when I try to run a query using ExecuteQuery, since no data returns and according to logs, Oracle is not receiving username's password:
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: 
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied
)

Weird thing is that both username and passwords are defined in Controller Services.
Has anyone gone through this issue before?
I'm currently using ojdbc8.jar and Oracle Server is 12c.
